# Loading Bitmap to Object using Aysnc

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am having an issue I am trying to load images from a web api. I can do it but when i try to put them into properties of an object it just crashes. I have look at all the examples of how to ASYNC load images i can find but everyone i find what to assign it to a imageview and not the object. below is Part of my source.

Here is an example of the calling code

```
     Movie Example = new Movie();       
     DownloadImageTask task = new DownloadImageTask();
                String path = "http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/original" + example.getProfile_path();
                example.setProfile(task.execute(path).get());
```

and Here is the method i use to get the image

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask() {
        this.bmImage = new ImageView(getActivity());
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try{
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap result = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        //set image of your imageview
        try {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
            //close

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "can't assign image to view");
        }

    }
}
```

I want something similar but instead of assigning to imageview it would return the image to the method that called it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is not much of a point in returning the image to the method that called it because this method would have to suspend itself and wait for the image to load, which defeats the purpose of letting the image load in parallel. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

If you really want to do that, I suppose it could be accomplished by modifying your AsyncTask like this:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private ImageView bmImage;

    private boolean finished = false;
    private Bitmap resultingBitmap = null;

    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try{
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        resultingBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finished = true;
    }

    public boolean isFinished() {
        return finished;
    }

    public Bitmap getResultingBitmap() {
        return resultingBitmap;
    }
}
```

And in the caller code:

```
DownloadImageTask task = new DownloadImageTask();
String path = "http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/original" + example.getProfile_path();
while (!task.isFinished()) { } // this defeats the purpose of parallel execution
example.setProfile(task.execute(path).getResultingBitmap());
```

You can however accomplish this as suggested in @Brandon 's answer:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    Example example;

    public DownloadImageTask(Example example) {
        this.example = example;
    }

    (...)

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        example.setProfile(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get the image display and save it in a Nonsql db. To store it i need to assign the bitmaps to objects

Comment: Then you can do it in onPostExecute() as suggested.

Comment: Sorry I thought i had edited the above comment. The Image loading code needs to be able to reusable. I currently use it to load around 20 images back to the object. The reason is the object is a movie. I am trying to figure out how to get all the pictures necessary to display the object without having to load them every time form the internet.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. A way of optimizing your code: you can pass a list of URLs to the async task and retrieve all the bitmaps at once. In order to avoid retrieving them from the internet every time, you can persist the bitmaps into files and load them afterwards. This is a subject to another question though.